# Riemann-Stieltjes integral, integration by parts (Rudin)

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Problem 17 of Chapter 6 of Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* asks us to prove the following:

> Suppose $\alpha$ increases monotonically on $[a,b]$, $g$ is
>   continuous, and $g(x)=G'(x)$ for $a \leq x \leq b$. Prove that,
>
> $$\int_a^b\alpha(x)g(x)\,dx=G(b)\alpha(b)-G(a)\alpha(a)-\int_a^bG\,d\alpha.$$

It seems to me that the continuity of $g$ is not necessary for the result above. It is enough to assume that $g$ is Riemann integrable. Am I right in thinking this?

I have thought as follows:

$\int_a^bG\,d\alpha$ exists because $G$ is differentiable and hence continuous.

$\alpha(x)$ is integrable with respect to $x$ since it is monotonic. If $g(x)$ is also integrable with respect to $x$ then $\int_a^b\alpha(x)g(x)\,dx$ also exists.

To prove the given formula, I start from the hint given by Rudin
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha(x_i)g(t_i)\Delta x_i=G(b)\alpha(b)-G(a)\alpha(a)-\sum_{i=1}^nG(x_{i-1})\Delta \alpha_i$$
where $g(t_i)\Delta x_i=\Delta G_i$ by the <strike>intermediate</strike> mean value theorem.

Now the sum on the right-hand side converges to $\int_a^bG\,d\alpha$. The sum on the left-hand side would have converged to $\int_a^b\alpha(x)g(x)\,dx$ if it had been
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha(x_i)g(x_i)\Delta x$$
The absolute difference between this and what we have is bounded above by
$$\max(|\alpha(a)|,|\alpha(b)|)\sum_{i=1}^n |g(x_i)-g(t_i)|\Delta x$$
and this can be made arbitrarily small because $g(x)$ is integrable with respect to $x$.

Comment: After you write out the discrete sums, you apply the mean value theorem (not the intermediate value theorem).

Comment: @chris. thanks. i will make the correction.

Comment: Because it is increasing monotonically and is continuous it is the case that it is integrable, so I think that these assumptions are fine -- perhaps not optimal but none the less good enough.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Compare with the following theorem,

**Theorem**: Suppose $f$ and $g$ are bounded functions with no common discontinuities on the interval $[a,b]$, and the Riemann-Stieltjes integral of $f$ with respect to $g$ exists. Then the Riemann-Stieltjes integral of $g$ with respect to $f$ exists, and

$$\int_{a}^{b} g(x)df(x) = f(b)g(b)-f(a)g(a)-\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dg(x)\,. $$

Comment: The discontinuity assumption doesn't seem to be necessary (Theorem 7.6, Apostol's Mathematical Analysis).

Comment: More precisely, $f\in R(g)$ already implies that there is no common point of discontinuity.

Answer (score 4):

You are right that continuity is a stronger hypothesis than needed. I haven't checked your proof in detail due to lack of time, but assuming $g$ to be continuous only simplifies the problem. See for example theorem $12.14$ in [This book](http://books.google.ca/books?id=nTHUVsVeaPsC&pg=PA182&lpg=PA182&dq=riemann%20stieltjes%20integral%20integration%20by%20parts&source=bl&ots=UObLhjLDiY&sig=VbTQH2NESl0e63Y6FifZsiTp7eQ&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=EzN4UOPAGrOq0AHEwICwBQ&ved=0CB8Q6AEwADgK#v=onepage&q=riemann%20stieltjes%20integral%20integration%20by%20parts&f=false).