# Solving Riemann-Stieltjes integral:$\int_{- \pi/4}^{\pi/4} f(x)dg(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, trigonometry, stieltjes-integral

I'm having trouble solving this Riemann-Stieltjes integral:

$$\int_{- \pi/4}^{\pi/4} f(x)dg(x),$$ where $$f(x):= \begin{cases} \frac{\sin^4x}{\cos^2x}{} &\text{if }x\ge0,  \\{}\\ \frac1{\cos^3x} &\text{if }x<0,\end{cases}$$

and $$g(x)=\begin{cases} \phantom{-} 1+\sin(x) &\text{if }-\pi/4 <x<\pi/4,  \\ -1 &\text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$

I believe the only jump discontinuities are at $-\pi/4$ and $\pi/4$. Which $g=-1$ at both of those points. I'm struggling with the rest. What formula should I be using to compute the integral and what should my answer look like? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Check this [theorem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211552/riemann-stieltjes-integral-integration-by-parts-rudin).

Comment: Can you elaborate how to solve the last integral in that theorem (related to my problem). I can see why I would use it since both f and g have no common discontinuities.

Comment: CAS says:$1-{\frac {7\,\sqrt {2}}{12}}+\ln  \left( 1+\sqrt {2} \right) $

Comment: If $g(x)=1+\sin x$ across the whole interval of integration, then $dg=\cos(x)dx$. And $f(x)$ changes at $x=0$. So can’t you just break it into two integrals?

Answer (score 1):

Let $T = \pi/4$. The first term in the Riemann-Stieltjes sum, $f(\xi_1)(g(x_1) - g(-T))$, does not tend to zero when $x_1 \downarrow -T$ and $\xi_1 \downarrow -T$, and similarly for the last term. The integral is
$$I = \int_{-T}^T f(x) dg(x) = \\
\lim_{\epsilon \downarrow 0} \{
 f(-T) (g(-T + \epsilon)- g(-T)) + \\
 f(T) (g(T)- g(T - \epsilon)) \} + \\
\int_{-T}^T f(x) \cos x \,dx = \\
2 \operatorname{arctanh}(\sqrt 2 - 1) + \frac {19 \sqrt 2} 6 - 2.$$
It can be verified that
$$I = f(T) g(T) - f(-T) g(-T) - \int_{-T}^T g(x) df(x) = \\
f(T) g(T) - f(-T) g(-T) - \\
\lim_{\epsilon \downarrow 0} g(0) (f(\epsilon) - f(-\epsilon)) - \\
\int_{-T}^0 g(x) \left( \frac 1 {\cos^3 x} \right)' dx -
\int_0^T g(x) \left( \frac {\sin^4 x} {\cos^2 x} \right)' dx.$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $g$ is differentiable on $-\pi/4 <x<\pi/4$ your integral changes to Riemann integral simply by the following theorem: $$\int_a^bf(x)dg(x)=\int_a^bf(x)g'(x)dx$$ so you will have $\int_{- \pi/4}^{\pi/4} f(x)dg(x)= \int_{- \pi/4}^{\pi/4}\frac{\sin^4x}{\cos^2x}d(1+\sin x)=\int_{- \pi/4}^{\pi/4}\frac{\sin^4x}{\cos^2x}\cos x dx$

Comment: The integral should really be $$\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} f(x) dg(x) = \int_{-\pi/4}^0 \frac 1{\cos^3 x} d(1+\sin x) + \int_0^{\pi/4}  \frac{\sin^4 x}{\cos^2 x} d(1+\sin x)$$ or $$\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} f(x) dg(x) = \int_{-\pi/4}^0 \frac 1{\cos^3 x} \cos x dx + \int_0^{\pi/4}  \frac{\sin^4 x}{\cos^2 x} \cos x dx$$

Comment: Psst... both of you need to take a closer look to what happens at the endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

> Since $g$ is differentiable there is no trouble with sum this boils down to Riemann integral of $g'\cdot f$

Namely [from here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral) we have $$\color{blue}{\int_a^bf(x)dg(x)=\int_a^bf(x)g'(x)dx}$$
Therefore, 
 $$\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} f(x) dg(x) = \int_{-\pi/4}^0 \frac 1{\cos^3 x} d(1+\sin x) + \int_0^{\pi/4}  \frac{\sin^4 x}{\cos^2 x} d(1+\sin x)\\=\int_{-\pi/4}^0 \frac 1{\cos^2 x} dx + \int_0^{\pi/4}  \frac{\sin^4 x}{\cos^2 x} d(\sin x)$$

But $$\int_{-\pi/4}^0 \frac 1{\cos^2 x} dx =\int^{\pi/4}_0 (\tan x)' dx =1$$

and
$$\int_0^{\pi/4}  \frac{\sin^4 x}{\cos^2 x} d(\sin x) = \int_0^{\pi/4}  \frac{\sin^4 x}{1-\sin^2 x} d(\sin x) =\int_0^{\sqrt{2}/2}  \frac{t^4 }{1-t^2 } dt\\=\int_0^{\sqrt{2}/2}  -t^2+\frac{t^2 }{1-t^2 } dt$$
 $$
$$

Comment: The first formula isn't applicable when $g$ has jump discontinuities.

Comment: @Maxim It is possible the discontinuities are of first order.

Comment: There are zero order discontinuities at the endpoints. See my answer.

Comment: @Maxim what do you mean by zero order discontnuity?

Comment: I mean that the function itself (the derivative of zero order) is discontinuous.

Comment: discontinuous mean non differentiable.

Comment: A discontinuous function is said to have a zero order discontinuity because, formally, we can say that the function is its own derivative of order zero. If your definition of the order of discontinuities is different, please state it. The upshot is that your answer is not correct because $g$ is not continuous from the right at the left endpoint and not continuous from the left at the right endpoint. You forgot to include the contributions from those discontinuities.