# Computation of a Riemann-Stieltjes integral

Tags: real-analysis

How do you compute the following? $$\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} f(x) \, dg(x)
$$
Given
$$f(x) = 
     \begin{cases}
       \dfrac{\sin^4(x)}{\cos(x)} & x \in [0,\infty)\\[6pt]
       \dfrac{1}{\cos^3(x)} &  x \in(-\infty,0)
     \end{cases}
$$
Alright, so we have a discontinuity at $0$. Can I just evaluate as:
$$\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} f(x) \, dg(x)=f(0)(g(0^{+})-g(0^{-1}))+\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} f(x)g'(x) \, dx$$
I get confused looking at examples, because the integral term always somehow goes to 0. I'm not sure if that's what happens in this case. The first term of the left hand side is $0$, so I think my answer here is $0$, but I'm not sure. Would appreciate an explanation for what happens to the integral term.

EDIT:
$$g(x)=1+\sin(x)$$ for $$x \in (-\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{4})$$ and $-\frac{1}{2}$ elsewhere

Comment: The fact that you have a discontinuity in $f$ seems to be no obstacle: this looks to me like an ordinary Riemann integral.

Comment: To clarify, there is some issue if and only if you have $a,b$ such that $g(b)-g(a) \neq \int_a^b g'(x) dx$. Otherwise you just integrate $f g'$ in the Riemann sense.

Comment: @Ian You need to take the endpoints into account as well, the condition that you wrote is violated if $a = -\pi/4$ or $b = \pi/4$.

Answer (score 0):

If you take $g(x)=1 +\sin(x)$ then  $\int_{0}^{\pi/4} f(x)\cos(x)dx=\int_{0}^{\pi/4} \sin^4(x) = \frac{1}{32}(3\pi -8)$ and $\int_{-\pi/4}^{0} f(x)\cos(x)dx=\int_{-\pi/4}^{0} \frac{1}{\cos^2(x)} = 1$. So $\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} f(x) \, dg(x) = 1 + \frac{1}{32}(3\pi -8)$

Comment: Answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2799784) for a slightly different $g$.