# Help understanding calculation of the expected value of a continuous loss variable integrating over the survival function

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics

I am reading an actuarial textbook (Nonlife Actuarial Models Theory, Methods and Evaluation by Yiu-Kuen Tse) and I want to understand the author's calculation of the expected value of a loss variable $X_L$  (defined as $$X_L = \left\{\begin{array}{l}
      0 , & X \leq d\\
      X-d , & X >d
    \end{array}\right\}$$
for some deductible $d$ and where $X$ is a continuous variable). To calculate $\text{E}(X_L)$, the author shows  $$\begin{align}\text{E}(X_L) &= \int_{0}^{\infty}{xf_{X_L}(x)dx}\\
                                           &= \int_{d}^{\infty}{(x-d)f_{X}(x)dx}\\
                                           &= -\int_{d}^{\infty} (x-d)dS_X(x)\\
                                           &= -\left[(x-d)S_X(x)|_{d}^{\infty} - \int_{d}^{\infty} S_X(x)dx\right]\\
                                           &=\int_{d}^{\infty} S_X(x)dx
                \end{align}$$

My question is about the justification for going from line 2 to 3 and then again from 3 to 4. From line 2 to 3, I understand we are using the equation $f_X(x) = -\frac{dS_X(x)}{dx} $ but how can we just substitute in the integral without having to change anything? Is this something related to line 3 being a Riemann–Stieltjes integral or something simpler?

For lines 3 to 4, from searching around, I found the accepted answer from this question [Riemann-Stieltjes integral, integration by parts (Rudin)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211552/riemann-stieltjes-integral-integration-by-parts-rudin) , so I was wondering are we making use of a similar theorem (I know below says to a constant and not to $\infty$) to get from lines 3 to 4 here?
The theorem in question: $$\int_{a}^{b} g(x)df(x) = f(b)g(b) - f(a)g(a) - \int_{a}^{b} f(x)dg(x)$$.

Comment: What is meant by $S_X$?

Comment: @FShrike  Probably the survival function $S_X(x)=\mathbb P(X>x)=1-F_X(x)$

Comment: The first question is just $f(x)dx=-dS_X(x)$, if you think of the $dx$ as some non-zero constant. The second part is indeed the integration by parts formula, but $f(d)=0$ and $S_X(d)=1$, so the result is zero. Which is why the term is missing.

Comment: yes, I meant the survival function. Also thank you but that’s not what I was asking. my first question was moreso what does it mean to integrate over a function and how does that affect the integral and the second part how do we apply integration by parts to integration over a function.