# Riemann-Stieltjes integration with floor function

Tags: analysis, integration

Evaluate $$\int_{\frac{2}{3}}^8 f(x)d\alpha(x)$$ where $\alpha$ is continuous and $f$ is the floor function, that is $f(x)$ is the greatest integer less than or equal $x$.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this? Maybe you mean $\alpha$ is the floor function?

Comment: I know how to evaluate if it is a specific function but an unsure how to when it is in the general sense.  It'd make more sense if it were $\alpha$ but the specific problem statement is not.  It is $f$

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206848/derivation-of-riemann-stieltjes-integral-with-floor-function).

Comment: I think the problem I am struggling with is that it is $f(x)$ that is the floor function. Do I just treat that simply as $\lfloor x\rfloor$?

Comment: The floor function is constant in most places. Split the integral up so that the floor function is constant over the range of integration.

Comment: Do you know how to evaluate $\int_a^b d \alpha(x)$?

Comment: I understand the breaking it up now.  I am working to understand the simplification of the integrals to get to the final answer.  Are you in agreement that the result should end up being what is shown below in the second answer?

Comment: Sue, yes, Marvin's answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Write $\int_{\frac{2}{3}}^8 \lfloor x \rfloor d \alpha(x) = \int_{\frac{2}{3}}^1 \lfloor x \rfloor d \alpha(x)+ \sum_{k=1}^7 \int_{k}^{k+1} \lfloor x \rfloor d \alpha(x) $.

What value does $\lfloor x \rfloor$ take inside these integrals?

Answer (score 1):

$$I = \int_{2/3}^8 \lfloor x\rfloor d \alpha(x) = \int_{2/3}^1 \lfloor x\rfloor d \alpha(x) + \sum_{k=1}^7 \int_k^{k+1} \lfloor x\rfloor d \alpha(x) = 0 + \sum_{k=1}^7 \int_k^{k+1} \lfloor x\rfloor d \alpha(x)$$
Now $\lfloor x \rfloor = k$ for $x \in [k,k+1)$. Hence, we get that
\begin{align}
I & = \sum_{k=1}^7 k (\alpha(k+1) - \alpha(k))\\
& = \sum_{k=2}^7 \alpha(k) (-k + k-1) - \alpha(1) + 7 \alpha(8)\\
& = 7 \alpha(8) - \sum_{k=1}^7 \alpha(k)
\end{align}

---

**EDIT**

To make the last step clear, let us explicitly write it out and see.
\begin{align}
I & = \sum_{k=1}^7 k (\alpha(k+1) - \alpha(k))\\
& = 1 \cdot(\alpha(2) - \alpha(1)) + 2 \cdot(\alpha(3) - \alpha(2)) + 3 \cdot(\alpha(3) - \alpha(2)) + 4 \cdot(\alpha(4) - \alpha(3))\\
& + 5 \cdot(\alpha(5) - \alpha(4)) + 6 \cdot(\alpha(6) - \alpha(5)) + 7 \cdot(\alpha(8) - \alpha(7))\\
& = -\alpha(1) + (1-2) \cdot \alpha(2) + (2-3) \cdot \alpha(3) + (3-4) \cdot \alpha(4) + (4-5) \cdot \alpha(5) + (5-6) \cdot \alpha(6)\\
& + (6-7) \cdot \alpha(7) + 8 \cdot \alpha(8)\\
& = -\alpha(1) - \alpha(2) - \alpha(3) - \alpha(4) - \alpha(5) - \alpha(6) - \alpha(7) + 7 \alpha(8)\\
& = 7 \alpha(8) - \sum_{k=1}^7 \alpha(k)
\end{align}

Comment: I dont understand what you are doing once you get to your summations, after eliminating the integrals

Comment: Why in the original statement do you change the limits of your summation?  am I missing why in one place we begin at one and one at 2?

Comment: @Sue The coefficient of $\alpha(1)$ is also $-1$ and hence can be clubbed with the summation.

Comment: ha thank you!  That was clear.  My mistake

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks. Corrected.