# Evaluate the Riemann-Stieltjes integral

Tags: analysis, integration

Given that $f$ is continuous and of bounded variation on $[a,b]$, evaluate $\int^b_a f(x)df(x).$

Comment: Integrate by parts.

Comment: [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral#Properties_and_relation_to_the_Riemann_integral) is a reference for the [integration by parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral#Properties_and_relation_to_the_Riemann_integral) of the Riemann-Stieltje integral.

Answer (score 3):

We will use the following [theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206848/derivation-of-riemann-stieltjes-integral-with-floor-function)

> **Theorem**: Suppose $f$ and $g$ are bounded functions with no common discontinuities on the interval $[a,b]$, and the Riemann-Stieltjes integral of $f$ with respect to $g$ exists. Then the Riemann-Stieltjes integral of $g$ with respect to $f$ exists, and
>   $$\int_{a}^{b} g(x)df(x) = f(b)g(b)-f(a)g(a)-\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dg(x)\,. $$

Now, in your case the function is continuous, which is nice, and of bounded variation that implies boundedness, so the theorem is applicable to our problem and we have

$$ \int^b_a f(x)df(x) = f^{2}(b)-f^{2}(a)-\int^b_a f(x)df(x) $$

$$ \implies 2\int^b_a f(x)df(x)=f^{2}(b)-f^{2}(a) $$

$$ \implies \int^b_a f(x)df(x)=\frac{1}{2}( f^{2}(b)-f^{2}(a)). $$

Answer (score 1):

$$d(f(x))=f'(x)dx$$
$$I=\int_a^bf(x).f'(x)dx$$
$$Put: f(x)=t$$
$$f'(x)dx=dt$$
So, $$I=\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)}tdt=t^2/2\bigg]_{f(a)}^{f(b)}$$
$$I=\dfrac{f^2(b)}{2}-\dfrac{f^2(a)}{2}$$

OR if $f$ has some discontinuities or not differentiable over $(a,b)$,We use By-Parts:
$$\int_a^b f(x)d(f(x))=f(x).f(x)\bigg]_a^b-\int_a^b f(x).d(f(x))$$
$$I=\dfrac{f^2(b)}{2}-\dfrac{f^2(a)}{2}$$

Comment: Bounded variation does not imply differentiable. So your approach does not cover the general case.

Comment: @julien Ok i'll add By-Parts too.

Comment: So what does the bounded variation allow us to do that we cant with simply the integration by parts formula?