# Riemann-Stieltjes Integral computation (step function?)

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Im trying to integrate this, using theorem 7.9 of apostol's book:

$$\int^{10}_0 f(x)d\alpha(x) $$

$f(x) = x^2$ and $\alpha(x)= 3\chi(7,9](x)$
Where $\chi(x)$ is $0$ everywhere except $1$ in the interval $(7,9]$

So using this theorem, and knowing the steps are at 7, and 9, and everywhere else the sum and substraction of $\alpha$ is $0$ i get:

$$f(7)[\alpha(7+)-\alpha(7-)] + f(9)[\alpha(9+)-\alpha(9-)] = $$
 $$= 7^2 (3*(1 - 0)) + 9^2 (3*(0-1)) = 3*7^2 - 3*9^2$$

Does this sound about right? In class we did a mostly theeoretical stuff with the R-S integral but not a single example so I'm i little lost.

Comment: It seems you lost a factor of $3$ from $\alpha$. Otherwise, it's fine.

Comment: Here is a [useful result](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206848/derivation-of-riemann-stieltjes-integral-with-floor-function).

Comment: http://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m321/step.pdf
I think the above proof is a general proof for such problems.
good luck