# Riemann Steiljes Integral when alpha changes

Tags: real-analysis, integration

For example if the question was following

> $$ \int_{0}^2  x\,d \alpha $$

where $ \alpha (x) = x $ if $ 0\le x\le 1 $ and $ \alpha(x) = 3x $  when $ 1< x \le 2 $

> Is it correct to solve it using
>
> $$ \int_{0}^2  x d \alpha  =  \int_{0}^1  x d x  + \int_{1}^2  x d (3x)? $$

If that is possible, does it mean that the value of $\alpha$ at $1$ is does not change the answer say if it was

$ \alpha (x) = x $ if $ 0\le x< 1 $ and $ \alpha(x)=3x $  when $ 1\le x\le 2 $ ?

Comment: See this [theorem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206848/derivation-of-riemann-stieltjes-integral-with-floor-function). $\alpha$ can have discontinuity.

Comment: Thank you! so as I said even if the value of $\alpha$ at the point of discontinuity was to change it wouldn't have an impact right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Have you studied any theorem related to this?

Comment: I have studied only the Reimann integrable criteria and if it is integrable how to find it using the Riemann sum as $ lim_{||P||\to 0}
\sum_{i=0}^n f(t_i) \Delta aplha_i $ and I wasn't sure if  an end pint changed whether the integral changes

Comment: Note that, you need to add $\alpha(1+)-\alpha(1-)$ to your answer. Or, alternatively, just use the theorem I gave you. See the posted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you *must* take account of the jump discontinuity of $\alpha$ at $x = 1$. The correct evaluation should be

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{2} x \, d\alpha(x)
&= \int_{0}^{1} x \, dx + 1 \cdot \{ \alpha(1+) - \alpha(1-) \} + \int_{1}^{2} x \, d(3x) \\
&= \left[ \frac{x^{2}}{2} \right]_{0}^{1} + 1 \cdot (3 - 1) + \left[ \frac{3x^{2}}{2} \right]_{1}^{2} \\
&= \frac{1}{2} + 2 + \frac{9}{2}
 = 7.
\end{align*}

Or as Mhenni Benghorbal pointed out, you can apply the Riemann-Stieltjes version of the integration by parts as follows:

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{2} x \, d\alpha(x)
&= \left[ x \alpha(x) \right]_{0}^{2} - \int_{0}^{2} \alpha(x) \, dx \\
&= 2\alpha(2) - \int_{0}^{1} x \, dx - \int_{1}^{2} 3x \, dx \\
&= 12 - \left[ \frac{x^{2}}{2} \right]_{0}^{1} -\left[ \frac{3x^{2}}{2} \right]_{1}^{2} \\
&= 12 - \frac{1}{2} - \frac{9}{2} = 7.
\end{align*}